# Package modify font size

Tags: packages, fontsize

I need to create a document and the ideal output would be 12pt calibri fonts with 1.5 line spaces. The created pdf seems like as if it uses the `\footnotesize`  font size instead of the set 12pt. Therefore, I thought it is caused by the caption package but when I deleted those rows I got the same output which is different from the expected output. I am using the following specifications and packages in this order.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\def\magyarOptions{defaults=hu-min}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, right=25mm, left=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Ábra}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Tartalomjegyzék}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Ábrajegyzék}

\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}                % label
  {0pt}             % sep 
  {\huge}           % before-code

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{calibri.ttf}[BoldFont= calibrib.ttf ,ItalicFont = calibrii.ttf ,BoldItalicFont = calibriz.ttf]



\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\arabic{section}.\ #1}}


\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\input{fejezetek/Címlap}
\small\tableofcontents
\footnotesize\listoffigures
\listoftables  
\chapter{Bevezetés}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{fejezetek/intro}
\chapter{Hedonikus modellezés}
\input{fejezetek/Elmelet}
\chapter{Gépi tanulás és az ökonometria}
\input{fejezetek/gepi}
\chapter{A vizsgált terület}
\input{fejezetek/location}
\chapter{Adatbázis}
\input{fejezetek/adatbazis}
\chapter{Szakirodalom összefoglaló}
\input{fejezetek/szakirodalom}
\chapter{Következtetések, Várakozások}
\input{fejezetek/varakozas}
\chapter{Modellek}
\input{fejezetek/modell}
\chapter{Összefoglalás}
\input{fejezetek/Osszefoglalas}
\chapter{Irodalomjegyzék}
\input{fejezetek/ref}
\chapter{Függelék}
\input{fejezetek/fugg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you have `\small` and do not limit its scope so it applies to the rest of the docuemnt

Comment: I gave a fuller answer below but there is only one use of `\small` in your posted code

Comment: @hair-splitter oops, thanks I'll add to the answer below:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\small\tableofcontents
```

applies `\small` to the whole document from that point.  If the intention is just to apply it to the table of contents then

```
{\small\tableofcontents}
```

similarly

```
{\footnotesize\listoffigures}
```

Comment: And `{\footnotesize\listoffigures}`

Comment: I modified in my document and indeed it was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @hair-splitter yes thanks, added